# divs wrapping - jsFiddle example

Tags: html, css

In the following jsfiddle I have put some html and some css.  I'm trying to not have each element wrap when the screen gets smaller.  Actually I'm trying to implement the jqueryUI slider inside of my container.  I've tried to implement several css fixes to get each element to line up side by side.  However they initially wrap.  If you play with the size of the results box for the fiddle below you will see that it does in fact wrap.

http://jsfiddle.net/webdad3/UaQQt/

What am I doing incorrectly

Comment: @generalhenry - Yeah sorry about that...  I just updated it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if I understand your question... You want all those seven-line tables arranged on one row, not wrapping under each other? If so, how about something like

```
.post-content { min-width: 85em; }
```

If you want them to stay arranged in a 3x3, maybe display:table is what you need...

Comment: yup...  I want them in 1 line (side by side).

Comment: Thank you.  That was the answer!